# How to create folder in root folder of the project?

Tags: java, file, jsp

In my project I'm trying to upload files to a drive in my system and when i try to access the file using browser it shows **Not allowed to load local resource: ** error. I think creating and uploading files to the project folder may solve the issue. How to do that programmatically in java?

```
private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "D:/dy/Stock";

File filee = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY);

                if (!filee.exists()) {

                    filee.mkdir();

                }
name = new File(item.getName()).getName();

item.write(new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
```

This is the codeI used to create and upload files to folder.

Comment: What exactly your question is?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I need to upload some pdf files and access these through browser.

Answer (score 0):

It won't. As a general rule, doing `file://` anything in a browser, these days, just does not work. Why not? It's complicated, but, to oversimplify: Security.

It has nothing whatsoever to do with the access rights of the process that asks the browser to load em. The browser just will not do this.

The solution, if you want to have resources open in a browser window from a locally running app, is to have your locally running app boot up a webserver (locally), and then ask the browser to load not, say:

`file:///Users/alvin/proj/myfile.txt`

but to ask the browser to load, say:

`http://localhost:8192/myfile.txt`

... which would work, if you start a webserver on 8192.

Comment: is there any way to create and upload files to the projects folder.

Comment: There is. It won't fix this problem so there is no point explaining how.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create folder in root folder, i don't need to open it.